# MYSQL - SELECT from different databases

Tags: php, mysql, select

How can I select data in the same query from two different databases into the same server?
This is what I'm doing, but my query doesn't works:

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM database_2.table_2 WHERE database_1.table_1.data_1 LIKE database_2.table_2.data_2";

$result = mysql_query($sqlquery);
$number = mysql_numrows($result);

$i = 0;
if ($number < 1) {
  print "DOH";

}else{
  while ($number > $i) {
    $content = mysql_result($result,$i,"database_2.table_2.data_3");
    print "$content";
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: define " doesn't work"? errors? you don't actully check if your SELECT query works or produces an error

Comment: Warning: mysql_numrows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /web/htdocs/...etc on line 88 [$number = mysql_numrows($result);]

Comment: that means the querry failed

Comment: why the `like` condition? can't you simply use `=` (it's cheaper)

Comment: And running the same query in any MySQL shell (or phpMyAdmin) would work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not about different databases.

Your WHERE clause references the field database_1.table_1.data_1 which was not supplied in the FROM clause.

Didn't you mean something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM database_2.table_2 
JOIN database_1.table_1 
     ON (database_2.table_2.some_field = database_1.table_1.some_other_field) 
WHERE database_1.table_1.data_1 LIKE database_2.table_2.data_2
```

?

Also,

```
echo mysql_error();
```

after your failed query - this will give you a clue about what's wrong.

Comment: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM database_2.table_2 
JOIN database_1.table_1 
     ON (database_2.table_2.some_field = database_1.table_1.some_other_field) 
WHERE database_1.table_1.data_1 LIKE database_2.table_2.data_2
COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    SELECT * FROM database_2.table_2 t2 INNER JOIN database_1.table_1 t1 
    ON  t1.data_1 = t2.data_2
```