# Mysql Select from 2 tables from 2 different databases

Tags: mysql

I got a problem like this:

```
                SERVER
    database_1          database_2      
    table 'names'      table 'eans'
+----+--------------+   +----+--------------+
| ean | name        |   |ean | size         |
+----+--------------+   +----+--------------+
| 10 | name1        |   | 10 | 100          |
| 20 | name2        |   | 20 | 255          |
| 30 | name3        |   | 30 | 310          |    
| 40 | name4        |   | 40 | 350          |
| 50 | name5        |   | 50 | 10           |
+----+--------------+   +----+--------------+


I need for my output this

+----+--------+------+
| ean | name  | size |
+----+--------+------+
| 10 | name1  | 100  |
| 20 | name2  | 255  |
| 30 | name3  | 310  |    
| 40 | name4  | 350  |
| 50 | name5  | 10   |
+----+--------+------+
```

I found that need to use UNION for it, but I don't know how the syntax is right.
*Can someone give me a hint to solve it?*

Comment: Please show the query you have written and also the errors and or incorrect data you retrieve.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476912/mysql-select-from-different-databases

Comment: thank you, solved it with the last comment in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply join between the tables like database.tablename.fieldname..like the following:

```
SELECT database_1.names.ean, name, size
FROM database_1.names
JOIN database_2.eans
     ON (database_1.names.ean = database_2.eans.ean)
```

Comment: maybe add some explanation

Comment: As the OP does not know how UNION works, i doubt he knows how JOIN works.